# Using Purrr::map2 to Loop Over Two Vectors of Column Names in Order to Conditionally Recode Multiple Columns into New Variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Using the sample code below, I want to use "mutate" or "mutate_at" to recode multiple columns into new columns based on the value of another column. Basically, I would like to recode the variables ending is "s" (q25s,q26s,etc...), based on the value of the corresponding non "s" variable. So for example, if q25 = 1, then q25s will be recoded so that 1 = 0, 2=0, 3=0, 4=1, 5=1, and 88=Missing, and the new name will be q25_new. If q25 does not equal 1, then is should not be recoded and q25_new should just be NA.

However, in order to achieve this I'm attempting to use tidyverse to create named vectors of column names, and then use "mutate", "recode", and "if_else" together with purr::map2.

I'm thinking something like the code below should be possible? I can't quite get it to work...and I feel like I need to use "paste0" somewhere to name all the new column variable names that start with "_new".

```
cols1<-Df %>%select(q25:q29)
cols2<-Df %>% select(q25s:q29s)

Df<- Df %>% map2(Df[cols1],Df[cols2],
  ~if_else(.x==1, mutate_at(vars (.y),funs(recode(.,`1`=0,`2`=0,`3`=0,`4`=1,`5`=1),"NA"))))
```

Here is the sample code.

```
Here is the sample code:
q25<-c(2,1,88,2,1)
q26<-c(2,88,88,88,2)
q27<-c(2,2,1,1,1)
q28<-c(88,1,1,2,2)
q29<-c(1,1,1,2,2)
q25s<-c(3,5,88,4,1)
q26s<-c(4,4,5,5,1)
q27s<-c(3,3,4,1,4)
q28s<-c(4,5,88,1,3)
q29s<-c(88,88,3,4,4)
Df<-data.frame(q25,q26,q27,q28,q29,q25s,q26s,q27s,q28s,q29s)
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output? Do want to keep `q..s` if `q..` is not equal to `1`?

Comment: If q.. is not equal to 1, then q..s should not be recoded, so I suppose q_new would then be NA.

Comment: See my comment to the other answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work ?

```
map2(Df[1:5],Df[6:10], ~ if_else(.x==1, recode(.y,`1`=0,`2`=0,`3`=0,`4`=1,`5`=1,`88` = NA_real_),NA_real_)) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  rename_all(paste0,"_new") %>%
  cbind(Df,.)

#   q25 q26 q27 q28 q29 q25s q26s q27s q28s q29s q25_new q26_new q27_new q28_new q29_new
# 1   2   2   2  88   1    3    4    3    4   88       3       4       3       4      NA
# 2   1  88   2   1   1    5    4    3    5   88       1       4       3       1      NA
# 3  88  88   1   1   1   88    5    4   88    3      88       5       1      NA       0
# 4   2  88   1   2   2    4    5    1    1    4       4       5       0       1       4
# 5   1   2   1   2   2    1    1    4    3    4       0       1       1       3       4
```

OK in the end I couldn't resist the challenge, so here's the pretty much 100% tidy way to go at it (same output) :

```
library(tidyr)
Df %>%
  mutate(n=row_number()) %>%
  gather(key,value,-n) %>%
  mutate(key2 = ifelse(grepl("s",key),"s","x"),
         key=sub("s","",key)) %>%
  spread(key2,value) %>%
  mutate(`_new` = if_else(x==1, recode(s,`1`=0,`2`=0,`3`=0,`4`=1,`5`=1,`88` = NA_real_),Inf)) %>%
  gather(key3,value,s,x,`_new`) %>%
  unite(key,key,key3,sep="") %>%
  spread(key,value) %>%
  rename_all(~gsub("x","",.x)) %>%
  select(order(nchar(names(.))),-n)
```

Comment: I like your answer, but can it be changed slightly so that if, for example, q25 is not equal to q, then q25s is not recoded, but instead is NA. The final q25_new should only contain 1,0, or NA. Sorry for not making that clearer in the question!

Comment: I guess to fix that I would just change the second .y to NA?

Comment: Also, just for my own learning, this method (your answer) works on the two vectors of column names, creates a new data frame, and then binds it back to the original. Is there a way to still use map2 but operate within the original data frame? That would be a preferred method if it's possible. If it requires a lot more code, then I'll stick with this current answer...

Comment: yes, you'd change the second `.y`  to `NA_real_` to be precise, if you want to distinguish these from those that come from the `88` value you could set one to `Inf`(depending of what you'd do afterwards). It's some more work to mqke it work within the df, i'm thinking of nesting column pairs into one, modify these list columns by adding the 3rd and unnest but that's some ninja wrangling for no performance gain, why would you want that ?

Comment: I edited my answer to be in line with your updated question

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll go with the first option lol But it's great to see how the second example would work and gives me something to practice. Thanks for taking the time for that!

Comment: you're welcome, instead of the 2nd mutate you'd usually use `separate` (not possible here as you had no suffix for 1st set of cols)  but appart from that I think it's a good textbook template for the whole tidy stuff when nothin quicker comes to mind